# Generating PDF from wkhtml using PHP wrapper, when sent back to Angular 4, opens only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, angular, pdf

I generate a html in Angular 4, send it to PHP wrapper for wkhtmltopdf, after that it is returned to Angular, and this works fine in Chrome, the PDF is displayed. I need it to be displayed also in Firefox. This is the code that sends the PDF to PHP:

```
public getPdf() {
    const html = this.pdfEl.innerHTML;

    alert(html);

    this.rest.post(
      '/pdf',
      { html },
      {
        headers: new Headers(),
        responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
      }
    ).subscribe(
      (value) => {
        //alert('subscribe receiver in pdf button directive');
        this.url = URL.createObjectURL(value.blob());
        open(this.url);
      });

  }
```

Things that I have tried so far, but none worked are:
1. Setting `this.url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([value.blob()], {type: 'application/pdf'}));` instead of `this.url = URL.createObjectURL(value.blob());`
2. Setting this as headers instead of `new Headers()` :

```
new Headers({ 
              'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
              'Accept': 'application/pdf'
            }),
```

any suggestions to resolve this, guys? Thanks.

Comment: My PDF display does not work also neither in Safari, nor in Firefox. I think it also wouldn't work in IE. This is not the same question as that one you stated. So, please remove that.

Comment: Flag has been retracted; I highly recommend you to modify your post title, in light of your last comment...

Comment: ????? I already did that yesterday!

Comment: Ok, sorry, that was another question. I changed this one too now.

Comment: upvoted for your follow through; hopefully you get some feedback from the SO community.

Answer (score 1):

If `value.blob()` returns a `Blob` you have also set the blob `type` to `application/pdf`. That has to be done on the response side, because the property is read only.

[Blob Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

> Blob.type Read only  A string indicating the MIME type of the data
>   contained in the Blob. If the type is unknown, this string is empty.

Or if you `value.blob()` returns only an array buffer you have to create a new `Blob` on your own.

```
new Blob([value.blob()], {type: 'application/pdf'});
```

Comment: I have just tried it: "this.url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([value.blob()], {type: 'application/pdf'}));" instead of "this.url = URL.createObjectURL(value.blob());". It didn't work on Firefox.

Comment: I do not know much about your server side, but can you manage to return MIME type `application/pdf` (accept header)? I am also using wkhtmltopdf but my backend is an aps.net controller returning an FileResult, which did not help in your case.